# Adding $.mobile.loading(''); to JQUERY MOBILE MULTI PAGES

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I use the following code for single page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.mobile.loading('show');
}); 
$ (window).load(function() {
    $.mobile.loading("hide");
});
```

When I use multi page template of Jquery mobile, the code only works on the first page of my app created by phonegap. How can I use them to all app pages?

Comment: I think you could use [before transition](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-beforetransition) using something like this:
*$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforetransition", function(event, ui) {
    // This is executed  before the transition starts
});*
but if I call show inside the function the loader widget doesn't seems to appear (maybe it gets closed so fast that there's no time to see it).

Answer (score 0):

JQM has page events which you can use.
You could show loading icon on **pagebeforeshow**
*eg*

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function (event, data) {
$.mobile.loading('show');
});
```

and hide icon on **pagehide**

```
$(document).on('pagehide', function (event, ui) {
$.mobile.loading('hide');
});
```

more info:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_page.asp

http://www.gajotres.net/page-events-order-in-jquery-mobile-version-1-4-update/